# PowerShell Hash of hash of hash: How to fill them?

Tags: powershell, hash

the final situation should look like:

```
   $BaseHash = @{
       "KEY_A" = @{
               "Hash2" = @{ "Txt"="descr"; "Val"=1.2;"End"=(get-date) }
               "Hash3" = @{ "Txt"="descr"; "Val"=1.2;"End"=(get-date) }
        }
       "KEY_B" = @{
               "Hash2" = @{ "Txt"="descr"; "Val"=1.2;"End"=(get-date) }
               "Hash3" = @{ "Txt"="descr"; "Val"=1.2;"End"=(get-date) }
        }
       "KEY_C" = @{
               "Hash2" = @{ "Txt"="descr"; "Val"=1.2;"End"=(get-date) }
               "Hash3" = @{ "Txt"="descr"; "Val"=1.2;"End"=(get-date) }
        }
   }
```

But I start with all hashes been 'empty':

```
   $BaseHash = @{}
```

Ok, I tried this get an Error but it seems to work?:

```
    $key1 = "KEY_A"
    $key2 = "KEY_B"
    $Topic= "Hash1"
    $Topic2= "Hash2"
    $defHash  = @{ "Txt"="Descr.";"Val"=1.2;"end"=(get-date) }
    $empty    = @{}
    $BaseHash = @{}
    if ( !$BaseHash.ContainsKey($key1) ) { 
        $BaseHash.Add( $key1, $empty  )
        $BaseHash.$key1.Add( $Topic, $defHash )
        $BaseHash.$key1.Add( $Topic2, $defHash )
    }
    if ( !$BaseHash.ContainsKey($key2) ) { 
        $BaseHash.Add( $key2, $empty )
        $BaseHash.$key2.Add( $Topic, $defHash )
        $BaseHash.$key2.Add( $Topic2, $defHash )
    }
    #$BaseHash
    foreach ($h in $BaseHash.$key1.GetEnumerator() | select -ExpandProperty name) {
      if ( $BaseHash.$key1.$h.Val -ne 0.0 ) { 
        Write-Host "Found $key1  $h  $($BaseHash.$key1.$h.Val) $($BaseHash.$key1.$h.Txt)"
      }
    }
    foreach ($h in $BaseHash.$key2.GetEnumerator() | select -ExpandProperty name) {
      if ( $BaseHash.$key2.$h.Val -ne 0.0 ) { 
        Write-Host "Found $key2  $h  $($BaseHash.$key2.$h.Val) $($BaseHash.$key2.$h.Txt)"
      }
    }
```

The error I get is at adding Topic and Topic2 to the key2-hash:
Exception at the call of Add with 2 Arguments: tThe element has already been added:

```
+ $BaseHash.$key2.Add <<<< ( $Topic, $defHash )<br>
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException<br>
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException<br>

+ $BaseHash.$key2.Add <<<< ( $Topic2, $defHash )<br>
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException<br>
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException<br>
```

On the other hand all seems to be added:

Found KEY_A  Hash2  1.2 Descr.
Found KEY_A  Hash1  1.2 Descr.
Found KEY_B  Hash2  1.2 Descr.
Found KEY_B  Hash1  1.2 Descr.

1) How can avoid the error message?
2) Can you suggest a better method to add hashes oh hashes to a hash?

Thanks in advance
Gooly

Comment: What's wrong with building it as your first code block suggests? Aside from a missing `@` before the first curly brace, and missing `"` after each Txt and before the =, it creates exactly what you want it to.

Comment: @ TheMadTechnician: Thank you! I just corrected the typos but I still get the error messages when I do $BaseHash.$key2.Add( $Topic, $defHash ) and $BaseHash.$key2.Add( $Topic1, $defHash ) how do I get rid of them? What is the problem? The complete (German) Error is: Exception at the call of Add with 2 Arguments: tThe element has already been added ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue. The problem is that you are using $empty as a blank hashtable, but then using it in another hashtable, and trying to re-use it later. At the point where you `Add( $key1, $empty )` you have set that hashtable as the value. When you call `$key1.Add()` You are executing the `.Add()` method of your $empty hashtable, adding members to it. By the time you get to doing anything with $key2 the $empty hashtable is populated with $topic and $topic2 already, so when you try to add those to it again you get an error.

Instead, just do `$BaseHash.Add( $Key1, @{} )` and go from there.

Comment: Don't be timid with PowerShell, fortune favors the bold. Honestly, you are over complicating the whole process by starting with blank hashtables and adding data after the fact. But if it works for you then go with what works.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
$BaseHash = @{}

$key1 = "KEY_A"
$key2 = "KEY_B"
$Topic= "Hash1"
$Topic2= "Hash2"
$defHash  = @{ "Txt"="Descr.";"Val"=1.2;"end"=(get-date) }

if( -not $BaseHash.ContainsKey( $key1 )) {
    $BaseHash[$key1] = [ordered]@{}
    $BaseHash[$key1][$Topic] += $defHash
    $BaseHash[$key1][$Topic2] += $defHash
}

if( -not $BaseHash.ContainsKey( $key2 )) {
    $BaseHash[$key2] = [ordered]@{}
    $BaseHash[$key2][$Topic] += $defHash
    $BaseHash[$key2][$Topic2] += $defHash
}

foreach ($h in $BaseHash.$key1.GetEnumerator() | select -ExpandProperty name) {
      if ( $BaseHash.$key1.$h.Val -ne 0.0 ) { 
        Write-Host "Found $key1  $h  $($BaseHash.$key1.$h.Val) $($BaseHash.$key1.$h.Txt)"
      }
    }
    foreach ($h in $BaseHash.$key2.GetEnumerator() | select -ExpandProperty name) {
      if ( $BaseHash.$key2.$h.Val -ne 0.0 ) { 
        Write-Host "Found $key2  $h  $($BaseHash.$key2.$h.Val) $($BaseHash.$key2.$h.Txt)"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you - I tried but still get the same Error: Error at +=-Opretator: The element already has been added. Key in the dictionary (? orig. 'Wörterbuch') "end" ...